# How to implement select ... as in NoSQL?

Tags: c#, mysql, mongodb, amazon-dynamodb, couchbase

I am very new to NoSQL so I am wondering how one would implement the following sql query in a NoSQL (DynamoDB, ...) way? is that even possible or would that take an entirely new approach?

The following query finds all records in a 200m radius around 38.698... longitude & -9.416...latitude (in the query longitude and latitude are fields in the table holding the respective gps values):

```
SELECT *, ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(38.6985559) ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * 
cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(-9.4186706) ) + sin( radians(38.6985559) ) * 
sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) )*1000 AS distance FROM locationtable HAVING
distance < 200 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 100;
```

How could this be implemented? I realize that several of the NoSQL DBs have some geo libraries but if above was all that is needed, would it be possible to "translate" this somehow?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry but too broad to answer for any more than one technology. It's also quite easy to find, if you understand what the SQL statement says. This is a standard "distance from a given point" query. And yes, all databases have their own specific methods for doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually do exactly that using N1QL, which is the SQL equivalent for JSON documents.
N1QL supports radians, cos, acos, sin, and every other trigonometric functions.
you should just try using Couchbase 4.5 DP and paste it to the query UI.

I checked it, it is working as is (almost, except for the "as" keyword), just swapping the table name to the appropriate bucket.

Answer (score 2):

I tried N1QL with an AS clause, it was accepted but didn't select properly. This worked for me:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
LET computedValue = yourFormula, other attributes...
WHERE condition including computedValue
```

Comment: trying this but still have some issues:

Comment: I did this: CREATE PRIMARY INDEX default;
SELECT *
FROM default
LET distance = ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(38.6985559) ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(-9.4186706) ) + sin( radians(38.6985559) ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) )*1000
WHERE distance < 200; the data I have is like this : {
  "business_name": "name",
  "categories": "type",
  "street_address": "street",
  "city": "city",
  "postcode": "90000",
  "phone": "",
  "website": "",
  "other": "other",
  "latitude": 38.6985559,
  "longitude": -9.4186706
}
 what I am missing?

Comment: Try removing the WHERE clause so you can debug your distance formula.